# Проектирование БД для задела на поиск множеств (схожее, релевантное)

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Я хочу написать свое первое веб приложение, но до того как начал что-либо делать - столкнулся с проектированием таблиц БД. Расскажу как выглядит сайт и в чем загвоздка (наверняка пустяковая, для тех кто с опытом написания сайтов и программ).
Мне нужно:
 - создать страницу с описанием человека и его предпочтения, также, на ней будет поле "похожи люди", но на основе его предпочтений
- вторая страница - само предпочтение (назовем вещью), оно может быть у многих людей в предпочтениях, и опять же, на этой странице должно быть поле "люди добавившие это", для релевантности подобранные по полю тематики предпочтения (которое указывается и у людей)

доп поля для предпочтения:
- id
- категория (тип)
- название
до поля для людей
- id
- имя
- категория (тип)
- предпочтения

Как спроектировать базу, чтобы поиск предпочтений и схожих людей был как можно быстрым, без лишних операций? Я слышал про инвертированный индекс, кое что стряпал по книжке, но толком ничего и не упомню, но что-то подказывает, что тут он был бы уместен. Как спроектировать поля "предпочтение"? Чтобы я не только мог выводить их в лоб на странице кому они пренадлежат, но и находить множества стравнивая с другими людьми?

Я не программист в типичном понимании, не учился на программиста и не знаю классических алгоритмов или паттернов проектирования БД. Прошу простить :)
заранее спасибо за помощь!